# Separate Active Record logger for daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, daemon

I've separated logging for a daemon by logging to a custom Logger object. The problem is SQL still gets logged to the main Rails logfile (development.log etc) and I'd want the SQL to end up in my custom Logger's logfile instead.

So I want to isolate Active Record logging to a separate file, but only for some processes (where I could set it up after the environment has loaded).

Comment: How do you start this daemon?

Comment: It's using the daemons gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/daemons), the _ctl file from daemon_generator (https://github.com/dougal/daemon_generator) requires application and environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved this by adding a separate Rails instance for the daemon, pointing at the same database. They each have their own log directory now.